# Creating an object out of an array of functions

Tags: javascript

Here's a function that allows you to convert an array of functions into an object of functions where each property is set to the name of the function.

```
var _ = require("underscore")

function functionName(fn){
  //http://stackoverflow.com/a/17923727/340688
  if(fn.name) return fn.name
  return /^function\s+([\w\$]+)\s*\(/.exec(fn.toString())[1]
}

function objecfify(arr){
  return _.chain(arr)
    .map(function(fn){
      return [functionName(fn), fn]
    })
    .object()
    .value()
}
```

Usage:

```
var model = objecfify([
  function create(){
    return "create"
  },
  function read(){
    return "read"
  },
  function update(){
    return "update"
  },
  function remove(){
    return "delete"
  }
])

console.log(model)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Why use the underscore at all.

For simple array manipulation, the **objecfify** can be modified as below:

```
function objecfify(arr) {
    var res = {};
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        res[functionName(arr[i])] = arr[i];
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to **reduce** an array into a single value (in this case, an object), why not use **[`.reduce()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/reduce)**?

```
function objectify(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(result, current) {
        result[functionName(current)] = current;
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

Reduce takes two parameters:

1. A reduction function, which in turn takes two parameters

   1. The previous value, as returned by the previous iteration of the reduction function
   2. The current value, changes with each iteration to reflect the current element

      <sup>*Note: The reduction function also takes two more, optional parameters. The index of the current element in the original array, and the array itself.*</sup>
2. An initial value, we're building an object, so our initial value is an empty object.

---

### Bonus

we can make it *more* general by passing the key generation function as a second parameter to `objectify`, then it can work with every array, even if they aren't functions:

```
function objectify(arr, keyFunction) {
    return arr.reduce(function(result, current) {
        result[keyFunction(current)] = current;
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

Then use like this:

```
objectify(arrayOfFunctions, functionName)
```